# Wordpress changing themes based on user agent

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've created two seperate themes. One for mobile, one for desktop. I've managed to change the theme with the function shown below. Changing the theme works, but the function still loads the CSS, HTML, JS and PHP code from the original and main theme.

Both the desktop and mobile theme have the same file structure and linking.

The folder structure is as follows

```
project
      |
      wp_content
               |
               themes
                    |
                    desktop
                    mobile
```

```php
function change_theme($current_theme)
{
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (strpos($user_agent, 'CostumizedAgent') !== false) {
        return 'mobile';
    } else {
        return $current_theme;
    }
}
add_filter('stylesheet', 'change_theme');
add_filter('template', 'change_theme');
```

I'd expect to load the themes actual files, not the files from the main theme. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use responsive styling, and not separate themes.

Comment: @rblarsen As the UX is completely different for both of the devices, it is not a viable option

Comment: You may want to check this once. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115417/27998

Answer (score 1):

Try this. wp_is_mobile() function helps to detect device

```
add_filter('body_class','mobile_theme_body_class');     
function mobile_theme_body_class( $classes ){
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ){
        return 'mobile';
    } else {
        return 'desktop';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```